# Error extraño al instalar MySQL en Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, instalacion

Manejo el sistema operativo Ubuntu 18.04 y he tenido un error extraño durante una simple instalación de MySQ.Esta instalación la hice con ubuntu 18.04 recién instalado por lo que es extraño solo introducí:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Y empezó la instalación y apareció el siguiente error: lo más extraño es que si funcionó la instalación pero no puedo acceder porque nunca apareció la pantalla para asignar la password.

Esta imagen es la instalación corriendo:

[image: Instalación corriendo]

La siguiente imagen es la instalación fallando y en ningun momento aparece el cofigurar password

[image: Instalación fallando]

La instalación finaliza y es posible ingresar a mysql pero no puedo acceder porque en ningun momento me dieron acceso a asignar una password
[image: Instalación finalizada]

Mas que una solución necesito una explicación ya que me gustaría saber que son los errores que aparecieron o a que se refieren, con gusto daré cualquier información que se necesite.

SSD: 240 GB 
Ubuntu 18.04.1
RAM 12 GB
Tengo particionado el disco en dos ubuntu y windows (desde hace mucho tiempo).

Update:
Al volver instalar con: `apt-get` apareció lo mismo pero con un cambio en los errores.
[image: Nuevo]

Comment: Posiblemente se trate de un error en el paquete de instalación de MySQL. ¿solo con este paquete te ha dado problemas? ¿tu instalación de Ubuntu es de 64 o de 32 bits?. He buscado sin éxito algún reporte de bug con el paquete de MySQL la única recomendación que he visto es el uso de apt-get en lugar de apt aunque no he visto ninguna advertencia con el uso de este último.

Comment: Lo que te comenta @AlvaroC es muy cierto. Trata de correr la instalación usando `apt-get`

Comment: Tengo Ubuntu 64 Bits y sí solo con MySQL,  ya intenté con  `apt-get` sin exito pero apareció una nueva linea lo actualizaré en la pregunta.

Comment: primero tienes una instalacion de mysql por eso es que sale acceso denegado a los proc que es la carpeta de procesos debes limpiar todo rastro de mysql de versiones viejas y luego `sudo apt-get auto-remove` o `apt-get auto-clean` o `apt-get remove` luego validar los servicios con `ps -ef | grep mysql` y luego si esta arriba `kill -9 id` del servicio y ya luego es que lo instalas una ves terminada corres `sudo apt-get install -f` para instalar packetes que no se actualizaron o que siguen siendo requeridos!

Comment: @Byro Ya Intenté desinstalé todo incluso borré la información de mysql guardada y seguí sus pasos, la primera instalación se llevó a cabo con un ubuntu 18.04 recien instalado, sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Answer (score -1):

Has intentado con este comando para configurar la base de datos:
sudo mysql_secure_installation

Te preguntará si quieres cambiar contraseña y usuario.

Comment: Ya lo he intentado. Pero al parecer no escribe la contraseña o no la guarda. Sale el error de acceso denegado.